# Error while setting up Allure Test Reporting in gradle project

Tags: gradle, allure

I would like to setup Allure Test Report for the geb framework using gradle (https://gebish.org/), but get the error below although json files are created in the results folder.

added allure.properties with the following content in `src/test/resources` (inside the project folder):

`allure.results.directory=build/allure-results`

also added this to build.gradle, which points to the correct location:

`systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', "$buildDir/allure-results"`

https://gist.github.com/rnemeth1980/df0f7ed46487fca13e8d412c23984fbb
shows parts of build.gradle

get the following error message:

`Cannot write to file '/home/abc/build/allure-results' specified for property '$1' as it is a directory.`

more detailed error log  https://gist.github.com/rnemeth1980/9c66bc96046086253c79275e88aef5d2

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by install 'Gradle Extension' plugin into Intellij.